# Truffle, Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a smart contract that is exposing a list of addresses:

```
contract AddressBook {

    uint public val = 1000;
    address[] public addresses;

}
```

Then I do truffle compile && truffle migrate --reset
After that, I run truffle console.

In the console, I bind the contract to a variable:

```
AddressBook.deployed().then(function(i){ab=i})
```

Now when I run:

```
ab.val.call()
```

It gives me back the proper result.

But when I run:

```
ab.addresses.call()
```

It responds with:

```
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the addresses variable is an array, so when you make a call use an element index number to access it.

```
AddressBook.deployed().then(function(i){i.addresses(indexNumer)})
```

or

```
ab.addresses(indexNumber)
```

Comment: It gives an error: Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid opcode

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: which client are you using

Comment: Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)
TestRPC v4.1.3 (ganache-core: 1.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build folder and run

`truffle migrate --reset --compile-all`

I had the same issue, the compiled code is corrupted. It works for the first time only and the subsequent compile corrupts the build. Hope it helps.